# Komar energy using Mathematica

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, computational-physics, software, kerr-newman-metric

I want to check [Komar conserved quantities](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1006.3445.pdf) for [Kerr Newman metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr%E2%80%93Newman_metric) using [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/). Is there any way to write a programming code for this?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: There are plenty packages in mathematica to compute the Christoffel symbols which are needed for this particular calculation. The simplest one is "GREAT". You just define your coordinates and you metric and you can compute the Christoffel symbols. Besides this i do not know a way to calculate Komar charges with mathematica. You can use the formula, perform the appropriate algebra in the integral, and the only thing left to do is to take the appropriate limit of some quantity that involves the metric functions and Christoffel symbols.

Comment: @Noone - a link to the package you name would be useful.

Comment: The link: https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/ID/4781/

Comment: It is actually a very good for your understanding to do it yourself. I have only basic knowledge of Mathematica, but have been able to do it for general metrics and dimensions quite easily.

Comment: The package linked above needs an .m-file, but in [this](http://yukterez.net/f/einstein.equations/files/66.html) file you have all the code in one file, including all the tensors and scalars needed for your purpose.

Comment: Might [mathematica.se] be better suited for this? It's otherwise not really anything we can recommend here

Comment: @Yukterez I have a question about your code. Why is one of the simplification assumptions $0<\theta<\pi/2$ rather than $0<\theta<\pi$? BTW, until I looked at your code, I wasn’t even aware that a Kerr-Newman-deSitter metric was known. Somebody should write a Wikipedia article for it!

Comment: @Ghoster - above and below the equator is symmetric, in that case it didn't make a difference. The only assumption that really made a difference was r>0, all the rest didn't change anything, I just left it in there. In the general code for arbitrary metrics the only assumption is that the domain is that of real numbers.

Comment: @Yukterez OK, thx. One more thing… I tried taking out the $\Lambda=0$. Everything seems to work relatively quickly until the Kretschmann scalar, the evaluation of which has been running for several hours. Is that expected?

Comment: @Ghoster - the Kretschmann scalar takes a long time for KNdS if smp=FullSimplify[], sometimes it is better to just use Simplify[] since that has a time contraint while FullSimplify[] tries everything it has, although the result might be the same as with Simplify[]. Since my computer already did the work you can also go [here](http://yukterez.net/f/einstein.equations/files/74.html#8) where the Λ is already included and the nb File is already evaluated.

Comment: @Yukterez Many thanks.

Comment: @Ghoster - if you're interested in KNdS, I updated the files [here](http://yukterez.net/f/einstein.equations/files/74.html#16) and [here](http://yukterez.rf.gd/f/einstein.equations/files/77.html?i=1#13) so they now also contain the analytical solutions for the 3 horizons and ergospheres (there are 4 solutions, but 1 is imaginary). For Λ you have to take the limit to 0 instead of actually 0 in order to recover the Schwarzschild or Kerr horizons since otherwise that solutions have divisions 0/0, but they work fine in the limit)

Comment: @Yukterez Thank you.

Comment: @Ghoster wrote: *"Somebody should write a Wikipedia article for it! "* - it's been a long time since I was on Wikipedia, but I created a draft, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draft:Kerr%E2%80%93Newman%E2%80%93de%E2%80%93Sitter_metric). The article is still a stub though, maybe others will join in to expand it, given the arcticle gets approves and published. I know the chat is getting a little offtopic, but since there are no private messages and the thread here is closed anyway I'll just use this chat for that (: